# Taking a string and diving it into a array given an regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have the following structure, either a single string array ['stufff sjktasjtjser ((matchthis))'], or the same structure in a nested array ['stufff', ['more stuff ((matchhere))'], '((andanother))'];
I can loop and match all regex in the brackets and even replace the text:

```
//after flattening the array lets take the first one, assume I am looping in the first element.
var matches = currentArrayElement.matchAll('fancyregex') //pretend I am matching the brackets
matchs.forEach(match=>currentArrayElement=currentArrayElement.replaceAll(match[0],'whatwhat'))
console.log(currentArrayElement)//'stufff sjktasjtjser whatwhat'
//but what I actually want is
// currentArrayElement = ['stufff sjktasjtjser','whatwhat'];
```

Does anyone knows how I can achieve that? Or any template lib that can do that within nested arrays? I need to output sometimes an array of a string ['tss'] and sometimes an array with an object [{}].

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to change the array in that index not the entire array.

Here is what I did then:

```
//after flattening the array lets take the first one, assume I am looping in the first element.
var matches = currentArrayElement.matchAll('fancyregex') //pretend I am matching the brackets
matches.forEach((match) => {
      currentArrayElement[i] = c.split(match[0]).flatMap(
        (value, index, array) => (array.length - 1 !== index
          ? [value, 'whatwhat',]
          : value),
      );
    });
```